# How to call shell command through VBA to delete current file?

Tags: excel, vba, cmd

I have written below code where if it did not find the license at predefined location, then this code will password protect the file and delete the current file.

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim thisWb As Workbook
Dim MyOldName As String
Dim MyNewName As String

Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook

FilePath = "C:\Users\Keshav\License.txt"
TextFile = FreeFile
Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
Close TextFile


If FileContent = "MACRO-yp3KhIL84NFKFa2uZTtNF7FRzTyvgykD" And Not Dir("C:\Users\Keshav\License.txt", vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub

Else
    MyOldName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    MyNewName = "License Expired"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & "\" & MyNewName & ".xlsm", Password:="yp3KhIL84NFKFa2uZTtNF7FRzTyvgykD"
    MsgBox "License has expired!!!!"
    Shell "timeout /t 20 del /F thisWB.Path\MyOldName", vbNormalFocus
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End If

End Sub
```

However, It is sending an error for file not found! Please Help!

Comment: hi.u missed a ":" in Dir("C\Users\Keshav\License.txt"...must be C:\Users... and on the FilePath too

Comment: Firstly, you forget to declare `MyOldName`, `MyNewName`, you split the first `If Statement`, you dont declare and set `FreeFile`  that s why you get the error.

Comment: And there are some other really obvious problems with the code.  But I'm afraid that I wouldn't help as what you are doing is fundamentally the wrong way of going about this and is potentially illegal under many countries laws.  (And to let you know, if I had this workbook I would be able to bypass this security permanently in a matter of seconds.)

Comment: I've edited the code. Debugged the same but this time even cmd window is not opening or it just disappeared. I need help in this shell code only.

Comment: u cant pass 2 commands (timeout and del) in simultaneous, and the path of the DEL command is wrong. try with Shell "cmd /c del /F " & thisWb.Path & "\" & MyOldName, vbNormalFocus.

Comment: whell, afterall u can pass 2 commands in one line, bur you have to put a & beetween the commands, like Shell "cmd /c timeout /t 20  & del /F " & thisWb.Path & "\" & MyOldName, vbNormalFocus

Comment: I am now able to perform this operation by simply adding a line " Kill MyOldName". Now I do not require anymore cmd commands. BTW thanks all for letting me understanding how cmd command is performed through vba.